# How to create nested arrays in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

```
<?php $mypeople=array("age"=>23,"fname"=>"sami","family"=>"soheili","job"=>"Dev", "father" => array("age" => 66
, "name" => "fara"
, "family" => "soheili"
, "job" => "clerk") );  ?>
```

I know this way for coding array in array but how I can use `[]` for it?

For example:

```
<?php $myarr=["name"=>"sami","family"=>"soheili"]
```

I want make another array inside the `[ ]`, is it possible? (without using `array()`)

Comment: `[]` is the short notation syntax for arrays introduced in PHP 5.4. Read more about [PHP arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
    <?php
    $myarr=[
        "name"=>"sami",
        "family"=>"soheili",
        "details" => [
            "telephone" => "072...",
            "email" => "test@yahoo.com"
        ]
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
This can be done dynamically too.  
<?php $arr = ["ar"=>"1","ar2"=>"2"];
    print_r( $arr ); // OutPut Array ( [ar] => 1 [ar2] => 2 )
    $arr["ar"] = ["ar11"=>"11","ar2"=>"2"]; 
    print_r( $arr["ar"] ); //Output Array ( [ar11] => 11 [ar2] => 2 )

?>
```